# Define a callback protocol in python that serves as structural supertype for any function that fits the following pattern

Tags: python, python-3.x, protocols, python-typing

I am trying to write a callback protocol that is a supertype of all functions that have a return type 'str' and also are able to accept calls with arguments like `(first_arg=some_int, second_arg=some_string, third_arg=some_float)`. The only requirement for functions in this family is that calls that conform to this pattern must be valid. (Some of the functions in this family may also be able to accept calls with a different set of arguments. This is fine.)

This is my attempt so far (I've neglected to implement the functions since they are irrelevant to my question about typing):

```
from typing import Protocol


class MyCallback(Protocol):
    def __call__(self, first_arg: int, second_arg: str, third_arg: float) -> str: ...


def example_function1(**kwargs) -> str:
    pass


def example_function2(first_arg: int, **kwargs) -> str:
    pass


def example_function3(first_arg: int, second_arg: str, **kwargs) -> str:
    pass


def example_function4(first_arg: int, second_arg: str, third_arg: float) -> str:
    pass


def invalid_mycallback(fourth_arg: float) -> str:
    pass


# All four of these identical function calls are valid.
value: str = example_function1(first_arg=1, second_arg="hello world", third_arg=4.0)
value2: str = example_function2(first_arg=1, second_arg="hello world", third_arg=4.0)
value3: str = example_function3(first_arg=1, second_arg="hello world", third_arg=4.0)
value4: str = example_function4(first_arg=1, second_arg="hello world", third_arg=4.0)

# Not valid, and will raise unexpected argument exceptions.
value5: str = invalid_mycallback(first_arg=1, second_arg="hello world", third_arg=4.0)


def call_func(callback: MyCallback):
    callback(first_arg=1, second_arg="hello world", third_arg=4.0)


# Mypy marks these three as invalid, even though we know that they are able to accept
# function calls that follow the pattern we've described above.
call_func(example_function1)  # Invalid but I think this should be valid.
call_func(example_function2)  # Invalid but I think this should be valid.
call_func(example_function3)  # Invalid but I think this should be valid.

call_func(example_function4)  # Valid as expected

call_func(invalid_mycallback)  # Mypy says this is valid, but it seems like it shouldn't be.
```

Is there some way that I can modify `MyCallback` so that it will be a structural supertype of `example_function*` (or any other function definition that fits the pattern described above) but not of `invalid_mycallback`?

I'm using python 3.8.

Comment: Do you mean: `def __call__(self, **kwargs):`?

Comment: mypy only sees example_function1 as an instance of MyCallback if I change the __call__ definition like you are suggesting @quamrana. I would like a protocol for which example_function1-4 are all instances.

Comment: I can't reproduce this precisely. For me, MyPy flags `example_function1`, `example_function2` and `example_function3` as invalid, which I agree seems incorrect. However, it does correctly identify `invalid_mycallback` as invalid. Can I ask which version of mypy you're using? https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.8&gist=156a4ce1c792c59fe5fd1b88cdcb35e1

Comment: Anyway, seems like this is a known bug in Mypy https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/5876